# Google publisher tag showing coloured box randomly

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, google-publisher-tag

[image]

I am trying to add googletags multiple times on the page. In some places on the page ads are displayed correctly and in some places, I see the box as shown in the attached screenshot.

Code sample:

```
const slot = googletag.defineSlot(
  options.addUnit,
  options.sizes,
  options.containerId,
)?.addService(googletag.pubads());

googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
// Disable initial load.
googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
// Start ad fetching
googletag.enableServices();

googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
```

The above code is called multiple times with some different slot level targeting parameters like 'pos'.

In total, I am calling it 8 times on the page and 4 times div elements are injected dynamically in the page. Sometimes I see one generic box sometimes two or at times 3, this behavior is random. See the second screenshot after I refresh the page.[image]